# Ckeditor_image Upload Error

Tags: image, drupal, image-uploading

I Configure Ck Editor & i am try to upload Image & Browse Image from server path it will get Error.
Error Statement here:
xml parse Error! & get Fatel error....

`cannot redeclare checnk authentication() in ckeditor/include/filemanager.config.php file & previously declared in ckfinder/config.php`

Pls give solution for that & What i will made to change!!!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a redeclaration of a function then you maybe importing the wrong files. Try going step by step in the installation instructions.

Probably you don't need one of those two files anyways. So you could try deleting one. and if it doesn't work deleting the other.